# Do Hillel & R Akiva contradict Mamrim 3 & Y"D 158:2?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, bein-adam-lachavero, contradiction

How do you reconcile Hillel (1) and Rabi Akiva (2) with the Mishnah Torah (3) and Shulchan Aruch (4)?

1. "What is hateful unto you, do not do unto your neighbor. That is the whole Torah, all the rest is commentary. Now go and study." - Hillel
2. "And you should love your fellow as yourself; this is a great principle in the Torah." - Rabi Akiva
3. "One who does not acknowledge the validity of the Oral Law... should be put to death by any person.... Like all the rest of the heretics who say that the Torah is not Divine in origin.... There is no need for witnesses, a warning, or judges for them to be executed. Instead, whoever kills them performs a great mitzvah." - Rambam (Mamrim 3)
4. "The apikorsim, and those who do not believe in the Torah and in the Jewish prophecy, it is a mitzvah to kill them. If one has strength in his hand to kill them with a sword, in public, he should kill him." - Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh Deah 158:2)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. There are many other instances in which we are told to do something harmful to others (e.g. execute a Shabbat violator). Is there something particular about your final two sources that make them troublesome, or is your question about how we can have any form of punishment or other mandated negative interactions with others, if those actions are presumably not things we would want done to ourselves?

Comment: Yes, the latter - these actions which Rambam and Shulchan Aruch call a mitzvah are certainly "hateful unto you" and violate at least the spirit of "love your fellow." I'm aware of no other instance in which halacha asks individuals to directly harm other individuals. Judicial proceedings are an altogether different matter.

Comment: Sure there are other instances. Halachah also tells us to stop a rodef (pursuer), up to and including wounding or killing him. (Related, and in this week's parsha: a householder may kill an intruder - he doesn't have to surrender his property rather than do so.) Another example: "zealous people" may kill certain kinds of violators of halachah (most famously, a Jewish man consorting with a non-Jewish woman, as Pinchas did to Zimri and Kozbi); etc.

Comment: @Meir, but severe punishments for interpersonal sins don't pose the same question Ruvi did. If I understand him correctly, Ruvi is asking that if everything is about being better to other people, how do matters of belief rise to do-or-die levels?

Comment: @MichaBerger, that might explain the first one, but not the second; a Jew consorting with a non-Jewish woman is (on the surface) not harming any other Jews by doing so. (To be sure, he does, because of כל ישראל ערבים זה לזה; but once you grant that, then the same is true of all areas of Torah, and the question falls away.)

Comment: @Meir - the Meshekh Chokhmah near the end of this week's parashah (Mishpatim) makes the point that every bein adam laMaqom is a bein adam lachaveiro because of "kol Yisrael areivim zeh bazeh". (Argument that "bazeh" is the correct girsa is left for another time. But it totally changes the meaning of the phrase: all Jews are intermixed, one with the other.") And it's only this that empowers beis din to get involved when someone violates a bein adam laMaqom. Arguing that for non-Jews, the mitzvah of setting up courts is specifically to enforce mishpat.

Comment: @Meir: but on point, when in an affair, each participant is doing psychological damage to the other. (Your specifying "Jew" is more related to your comment on Al Berko's answer.)

Comment: @MichaBerger, but who says we're talking only about an affair? Presumably קנאים פוגעים בו would apply equally well if they were married in a civil ceremony. (Also, the mishnah there mentions two other examples where this applies, one of them being המקלל בקוסם, where there doesn't seem to be any "bein adam lachaveiro" component at all.)

Comment: @Meir - qana'im pog'im bo doesn't apply if you had some advanced warning. It's an "in the moment" thing. The second it could be premeditated, you should have gone to beis din. In fact, "affair" is more lashon sagi nahor than accurate.

Comment: @MichaBerger, not really. It is הלכה ואין מורין כן, true, but all that means is that the kanai shouldn't be asking beis din what to do, just act. But suppose Zimri married Kozbi in a civil ceremony years ago, and Pinchas finds out only now - why would we say that this halachah is inapplicable? (Also, we're still talking about only one of three cases of קנאים פוגעים בו, but this still leaves the others unaddressed.)

Comment: Qanaim pog'im bo is only if motivated by the passion of the moment, ruach qin'ah lichvod Hashem amitit. If there was chance of forethought, no. It also has to be that the bi'ah was beharhesia and that it didn't end with hasra'ah. (Rama CM 425:4) The befarhesia part would also be more than any metaphysical kol yisrael areivim communal damage -- it's a public spectacle.

Comment: I’d imagine it’s the other way around, that the Rambam and Tur/Mechaber, who came later, potentially contradict these Tannaim.

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous ways of reconciling those principles:

1. In general, we hold that the positive approach (like to love thy fellow) is limited to "one's Jewish fellow", namely another pious Jew, and does not apply to wicked ones. THere's no obligation of loving the sinners, following the Passuk (Psalms 97, 10) "אוהבי ה' שנאו רע"
2. By reprimanding or punishing or even killing the wicked we actually do good to them and to the world - to them as they do Teshuva and increase their merits, and to the world accordingly.
3. We can explain that just as other Mitzvos can contradict and we're obligated to choose one, like Shabbos and Pikuach Nefesh, or Kibud Av vs Talmud Torah, those positive Mitzvos hold unless we're commanded otherwise, i.g stone the Shabbos breaker.

Comment: "Ben Azzai said, a greater principle than that [Rabbi Aqiva's] is 'these are the generations of Adam'." So, I seriously question #1.

Comment: @MichaBerger, הלכה כר' עקיבא מחבירו.

Comment: @Meir: this is neither halakhah nor necessarily a machloqes. Ben Zoma is one-upping R' Aqiva with "gedolah mizu" -- does that means he disagrees, or that he found a bigger way to make the same point? But in any case, even if we assume R Aqiva disgrees with the point being made, rules of pesaq don't apply to an argument about aggadita.

Comment: @MichaBerger עקיבא מה לך אצל הגדה

Comment: @Alex: meaning? Are you trying to say that R Aqiva didn't mean this kelel gadol in an aggadic sense so that rules of machloqes should apply? Or that Rabbi Aqiva's opinion should be downgraded because it is indeed a debate outside his specialty? Either way, I personally believe my first option -- Ben Zoma is one-upping R Aqiva, not really disagreeing with him.

Comment: Oh, and on the OP... I just realized that אהבי ה שנאו רע is open to Beruriah's יתמו חטאים ולא חוטאים critique.

Comment: @MichaBerger The second one.